# Use table columns in Exec stored procedure command SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a command:

```
exec [Database].[dbo].DepartmentChangeLevel , Department, Date, Level;
```

I currently specify the values manually and explicitly like this:

```
 exec [Database].[dbo].DepartmentChangeLevel , 'Catering', '20180101 08:01:00', 3;
```

However, I want to run the same command and use values from a table - like this:

```
exec [Database].[dbo].DepartmentChangeLevel 
     select 
         [Department], [Date], [Level]
     from
         [Database].[dbo].[DepartmentChange]
```

The error message I get is

> Expects parameter @department which is not supplied

Please help

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. Use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine). This requires rewriting your stored procedure. If that's absolutely not an option, you can use a loop with a cursor, but performance will likely be rubbish.

Comment: What does the stored procedure do? If the values come from the table you could write a different stored procedure that joined with `DepartmentChange` without passing anything through parameters.

Comment: You need to **load** those values from the table into SQL variables - then you can use these variables in the call to `EXEC` - but you **cannot** directly have a `select` in the middle of an  `EXEC` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Cursor instead:

Create a Cursor on your table and pass all three columns into three variables
and execute proc in the cursor.

Example :

```
    declare db_cursor cursor 

    for select 
             [Department], [Date], [Level]
         from
             [Database].[dbo].[DepartmentChange];

    declare @department int --your column data type
            ,@date datetime --your column data type
            ,@level varchar(10) --your column data type

    OPEN db_cursor;

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @department, @date, @level;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

    BEGIN  
        exec [Database].[dbo].DepartmentChangeLevel @department, @date, @level;
        DELETE FROM [Database].[dbo].DepartmentChangeLevel ---or you can store values from DepartmentChangeLevel table into temporary table  then delete those values from temporary table
            WHERE [Department]=@department
            and [Date]=@date
            and [Level]=@level

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @department,@date, @level

    END

    CLOSE db_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```